# Waiting time to be served in a restaurant

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Suppose you are at a restaurant with $m$ customers in, and everyone in the restaurant is waiting to be served their food. There are $n\leq m$ people at your table (including you), and as a polite person you will wait for everyone at the table to be served before you eat.

If at time $t=0$ the restaurant starts serving one person every second, with each person they serve being selected at random from the people who have not yet got their food, how long do you expect to wait before everyone at your table has their food?

I can think of the obvious combinatorial sledgehammer approaches, but I was hoping for a more aesthetic solution.

Comment: What in your mind are the obvious approaches?

Comment: @MishaLavrov considering all the combinations of possible ways food can come out, the time it would take for the table to be served completely, and multiplying by probabilities and summing

Comment: You have tagged Poisson distribution but nowhere mentioned it in your question. What's up with that?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron that was someone else’s edit, nothing to do with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable describing the first moment when your whole table has been served. You can solve your problem using the formula $E[X] = \sum_{T=0}^\infty P(X>T)$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)).

To serve our whole table by time $T$, we need all of our friends to be among the first $T+1$ people served (since you've specified that someone gets served at time $0$, so there are $T+1$ people served by time $T$). Thus we have $$P(X \le T) = \frac{\binom{T+1}{n}}{\binom{m}{n}}.$$

Now we can plug in and simplify the expected value:
\begin{align}
E[X]
&= (n-1) + \sum_{T=n-1}^{m-1} \left(1 - \frac{\binom{T+1}{n}}{\binom{m}{n}}\right) \\
&= m - \frac 1 {\binom m n} \sum_{T=n-1}^{m-1} \binom{T+1}{n} \\
&= m - \frac 1 {\binom m n} \sum_{T=n}^m \binom{T}{n} \\
&= m - \frac{\binom{m+1}{n+1}}{\binom m n} \\
&= m - \frac{(m+1)! n! (m-n)!}{m!(n+1)! (m-n)!} \\
&= m - \frac{m+1}{n+1} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{mn-1}{n+1}}
\end{align}

---

I guess maybe this is the kind of "combinatorial sledgehammer" you were hoping to avoid. But a) I'm not sure, it might be a helpful solution to you, and b) knowing the final formula may help you or others come up with a slicker way to prove the same result.

Comment: Thanks this is great, definitely less sledgehammer-y than my solution. Nice idea to use the alternative formula for expectation

Answer (score 4):

Certainly you will have to wait at least $n-1$ seconds to eat (in the absolute luckiest scenario, everyone at your table is served at times $0, 1, \dots, n-1$).

Beyond that, each of the $m-n$ other customers can force you to wait an extra second. The probability that a given customer forces you to wait is $\frac{n}{n+1}$: the probability that of the $n+1$ people including that customer and your entire table, the customer is not last.

By linearity of expectation, the $m-n$ other customers force us to wait $(m-n) \cdot \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{mn-n^2}{n+1}$ extra seconds. Adding the $n-1$ seconds we were guaranteed to wait gives $\frac{mn-n^2}{n+1} + \frac{n^2-1}{n+1} = \frac{mn-1}{n+1}$ seconds.